# unable to display the validation messages from @Html.ValidationSummary() in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have a fairly simple form created in a partial view and loading the form on a jquery dialog. The view is tightly bound to a model. When the user clicks on the submit button with out entering any inputs, I need to show the validation messages.

```
<div>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ssimForm" action="Home/ProcessUploadedFile"
    onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>
        <h3>
            Select the file to be uploaded :</h3>
        <span>
            <input type="file" name="UploadFileName" id="UploadFileName" /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>
            Select the date range :</h3>
        <span class="uslabel">From Date(MM/dd/yyyy): </span>
        <input class="usdate" id="usfromdate" name="StartDate" type="date" />
        <span class="uslabel">To Date(MM/dd/yyyy): </span>
        <input class="usdate" id="ustodate" name="EndDate" type="date" />
    </div>    
    <div>
        <br />        
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Process File" />
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="message-success">
        <span>@ViewBag.Confirmation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message-error">
        <span>@ViewBag.Error</span>
    </div>
    </form>  
</div>
```

Now comes the actual problem. when I submit the form I am able to see the validationSummary object populated with the messages, but they are not getting rendered on the screen.

I am able to see the messages if I replace the content of the dialog with the response from the jquery ajax call, that fetches the entire view from the server side. I do not want to take this approach as I beleive this is not the correct way to return validation summary in MVC.

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't have the `@using (Html.BeginForm()) { }` block.

Here is my blog post for a quick and easy way to set up Validation Summary + Unobtrusive Validation for MVC3+.
http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2011/01/28/aspnet-mvc-3-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-unobtrusive-javascript.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your post. The actual problem was with IE's way of repopulating the modal window after post back via ajax. It is stripping of the form tags. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-jquery-stripping-form-tags